# Finding solutions to $M^3+2M^2-5M-6I=0$ for a matrix $M$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

> Find all matrices of the form $\left(\begin{array}{} a & c\\0&b \end{array}\right)$ which satisfy the equation: $$M^3+2M^2-5M-6I=0 $$

Before this part of the question we needed to show that:
$$ M^3+2M^2-5M-6I=(M+I)(M-2I)(M+3I)$$
and that if you have $AB=0$ for some square matrices $A$ and $B$ then either $\det A=0$ or $\det B=0$ or $\det A=\det B=0$. Next it asked if $\det{B}\neq 0$ then what did $A$ have to be (I got $A=0$ since $B$ is invertible so $ABB^{-1}=0B^{-1}$ so $A=0$).

---

The thing I'm stuck on is that when I try to use the method hinted at in the question I only get the solutions $M=-I$, $M=2I$ and $M=-3I$ (so $c=0$) but I know from explicitly working out the product $(M+I)(M-2I)(M+3I)$ that you get more solutions (with $c\neq 0$).

My reasoning went like: let $\det (M+I)\neq 0$ so that we need only consider $(M-2I)(M+3I)=0$ where if $\det (M-2I)\neq 0$ then $M=-3I$ or $\det (M-3I) \neq 0$ then $M=2I$. Repeating this reasoning for all the cases seems to only give $M=-I,2I,-3I$. Any hints as to where I'm going wrong to miss the other solutions would be great!

Comment: In the example you worked out above, you assume either $\det (M-2I) \neq 0$ or $\det(M-3I) \neq 0$ but leave out the case $\det(M-2I) = \det(M-3I) = 0$. The latter is certainly possible - take for example $\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ 0 & 3\end{pmatrix}$ (I'm not claiming that this is a solution, just that you're missing out a possible case)

Comment: @stochasticboy321 Yeah I'm wondering whether it's because I've missed something like this. Another part to the question was to show that $\det A=0$ and $\det B=0$ doesn't imply $AB=0$. So I'm not sure in the case you mention whether that would a solution to the equation or not. Though I'm not entirely sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you knw that *at least* one of the three factors must have determinant $0$, that is
$$\tag1 (a+1)(b+1)=0\quad\text{or}\quad(a-2)(b-2)=0\quad\text{or}\quad(a+3)(b+3)=0.$$
The first says that at least one of $a,b$ equals $-1$, the second says one equals $2$, the third says one equals $-3$. *At most* two of these are possible (e.g., we could have $a=-1$ and $b=2$, but then $(a+3)(b+3)=10\ne0$).
As you already solved the case that *exactly* one of $(1)$ holds, the case of *exactly two* remains to be considered. Up to swapped rows and columns, this is about matrices of the form
$$ \begin{pmatrix}-1&c\\0&2\end{pmatrix}\qquad\begin{pmatrix}-1&c\\0&-3\end{pmatrix}\qquad\begin{pmatrix}2&c\\0&-3\end{pmatrix}$$
For example for the first note that (for arbitrary $c$) $$(M+I)(M-2I)=\begin{pmatrix}0&c\\0&3\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}-3&c\\0&0\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Thanks! I thought that I was missing something. Just a quick question, how did you know that $(M+I)(M-2I)=0$ (where $M$ is one of the three matrices you gave) without explicitly doing the multiplication? For example in your last example $\det (M-3I) \neq 0$ but $\det (M+I)=\det (M-2I)=0$. In part of the question we're asked to prove that $\det A =0$ and $\det B=0$ doesn't imply that $AB=0$. But as you show it *is* the case that $(M+I)(M-2I)=0$. I'm just wondering if there's something that shows this is the case without working it out with matrix multiplication.

Comment: Actually it makes sense since if you take two matrices of the required form with determinant zero ($ab=0$ and $a'b'=0$) and multiply them you get: $\left(\begin{array}{} a & c\\0&b \end{array}\right) \left(\begin{array}{} a' & c'\\0&b' \end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{ccc} aa' & ac'+cb'\\0&bb' \end{array}\right)$ where in this case it has the condition that $a\neq a'$ and $b\neq b'$ which then implies it must be the zero matrix. I was just wondering whether there was a nicer way to see it.